# How to query JSON data in PostGre in Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

so in my table there is a `criteria` column the data inside criteria looks like this

```
{
    "maxAq": 146461,
    "minAq": 109839,
    "validEnd": {
        "date": "2018-04-04 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "timezone_type": 3
    },
    "acceptEnd": {
        "date": "2018-04-05 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "timezone_type": 3
    },
    "supplierId": 3,
    "validStart": {
        "date": "2017-04-04 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "timezone_type": 3
    },
    "acceptStart": {
        "date": "2017-04-05 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "timezone_type": 3
    },
    "distributor": 22,
    "productType": "gas"
}
```

Now I am trying to query the rows which has `validStart`  I am using laravel for this

query looks like this

```
if($request->validStart !='')
          $result->where('criteria->validStart->date','=',$request->validStart);
$r = $result->where('criteria->productType','=',"gas")->take(20)->get();

        return Response::json($r);
```

So basically I am trying to do somehting like this

`criteria->validStart->date  = date`

but I am getting empty result even though there are few rows with that exact date .

the url is like this

```
price_filter_gas/?distributor=22supplierId=3&validStart=2017-04-04
```

if you can check the json it does have all these parameters

Any suggestion is welcome

thanks

Comment: Follow this syntax to filter json column data https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the column name to a variable first:

```
$col1 = 'criteria' . '->' . 'validStart' . '->' . 'date';
$col2 = 'criteria' . '->' . 'productType';
```

And then use it in the where clause

```
$result->where($col1,'=',$request->validStart);
$r = $result->where($col2,'=',"gas")->take(20)->get();
```

Due to the weird way of Laravel adding quotes while generating the sql, this is the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: The operator `->` in $col1 and $col2 works when you run the query in tinker. But if it doesn't work for you from code, try replacing it with `->>`

Comment: that was not the issue ,since the json is just a string the issue was in the pattern matching , if you see the `validStart=2017-04-04` input that date format and the date format in Json is different `(yy-mm-dd),(yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` , I think that is the issue

Comment: Did you try using '>' operator in your where clause to see if that is working as expected?